# Is there a way to use generalized do blocks?

Tags: haskell

I want to create a Configuration Dictionary, so Haskell can be used similar to TOML.
For that purpose I have created the structure "Dictionary"

```
Dictionary a
  = Section [(String, Dictionary a)]
  | Point a

key @ dictionary = Section [(key, dictionary)
key |= value = Section [(key, Point value)]
```

Now via semigroups I can merge two dictionaries to create a new one:

```
example_configuration =
  "resolution" @ "width" |= 1920
  <> "resolution" @ "height" |= 1080
```

But I think always having to combine via the semigroup operator is noisy.

Initially, I wanted to implement Monad for dictionaries, so I could use the do block. But monads naturally need to allow transforming old values. That is something I dont want. Is there a way to create a custom block notation (like do) for another operator instead of bind?
Maybe like this:

```
example_configuration = combine
  "resolution"@"width" |= 1920
  "resolution"@"height" |= 1080
```

Comment: IIRC, do-blocks also work with Applicative... but I'm not sure that helps you.

Comment: I'd recommend against using Haskell as a configuration language. If you want something *designed* for configuration files that retains a lot of the essence of Haskell, I'd recommend [Dhall](http://dhall-lang.org).

Comment: (Dhall is strongly and statically typed, and more importantly, *not* Turning-complete, so you can define functions to reduce boilerplate without worrying about infinite loops.)

Comment: List notation essentially requires only a single comma per line. I'd use that. (Also, your type parameter `a` is unused -- do you really need that?)

Comment: Perhaps it is possible to "(ab)use" `do` notation for this, but this is often done through lists, not through a `do` notation.

Comment: @chepner On the other hand, xmonad for example has gotten a lot of mileage out of allowing its configuration language to be Turing complete.

Comment: I'll say I'm aware of Xmonad and leave it at that.

Comment: Consider using `mconcat` or `fold` and pass the arguments with a list notation.

Answer (score 5):

You can turn any monoid into a monad, as it were, by wrapping it in [`Writer`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.6.1.1/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Writer-CPS.html#t:Writer), or just by adding a type argument that's used exactly once in the data structure:

```
data Dictionary a r
  = Section [(String, Dictionary a ())] r
  | Point a r

instance Monad (Dictionary a) where
  return = Section []
  Section ls q >>= f = Section ls () <> f q  --ish, some type matching is required
```

And then you can just use ordinary `do` syntax

```
example_configuration :: Dictionary Int ()
example_configuration = do
  "resolution"@"width" |= 1920
  "resolution"@"height" |= 1080
```

Is this a good idea? Debatable. It could certainly be argued that this is just abusing `do` syntax for something quite un-monadic. On the other hand, it can actually be quite convenient to abuse this syntax, in particular because it often allows omitting paretheses. In fact, I sometimes use `do` on values that aren't even monadic *at all* for this one reason - as long as there's only one statement in a `do` block, no monad operators are needed and the `do` simply acts as a paretheses that's auto-closed when indentation drops back to the previous level. Still abuse, but quite useful. An example where this is done is [HaTeX](https://gitlab.com/daniel-casanueva/haskell/HaTeX), which e.g. I used for writing my entire PhD thesis in Haskell.

For *configuration* files however I would [agree with chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78200215/is-there-a-way-to-use-generalized-do-blocks#comment137864159_78200215) that it's not a good idea to use Haskell, or another Turing-complete language, but instead better something dedicated like [Dhall](https://dhall-lang.org/).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `do` notation with the tuple instance of `Monad`.

```
key @ dictionary = (Section [(key, fst dictionary)], ())
key |= value = (Section [(key, Point value)], ())

exampleConfiguration = fst $ do
  "resolution" @ "width" |= 1920
  "resolution" @ "height" |= 1080
```

Comment: Off topic, but actually `@` works fine as an operator as long as you're careful with whitespace.  With the `TypeApplications` extension turned on, `x@y` is a pattern, `x @y` is a type application, and `x @ y` in an operator call, I believe.

Comment: @K.A.Buhr Fixed, thank you! I had indeed been insufficiently careful about whitespace in my local test.